# Eclipse: Change overrides in all implementing classes

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Im wondering how to fix all classes which implements a special interface at onece when I've just changed the declarations within the interface.

For example I've removed a method signature from my Interface `ISomething` and I want to run in every class which is implementing `ISomething` the action to remove the unused `@override` annotations (Or vice versa if I add some definitions).

Is there something in eclipse which can help here?

Comment: Deletion doesn't seem to be possible, check this link https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/215637/why-delete-method-field-function-refactoring-doesnt-exist-in-eclipse

Comment: Do you want to remove only `@Override` annotation or the whole method?

Answer (score -2):

The only thing Eclipse will do for you is show a bunch of error markers when you add or remove methods from an interface. You'll have to take care of than manually.